# Hacer un insert en java después enseguida de otro insert

Tags: java, mysql

Una vez que inserto en una tabla como realizar otra inserción enseguida, pero obteniendo el id del ultimo registro que se acaba de insertar.
En mi tabla usuario ya inserto con el siguiente codigo:

> Tabla usuario
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> Metodo de guardar

```
public static int save(UsuarioBean usu_bean){
    Connection con = null;
    int status=0;  

    try{  
        con = Conexion.getConnection(); 
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(  
                     "insert into usuario (nombres, a_paterno, a_materno, direccion, telefono) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");  
        ps.setString(1,usu_bean.getNombre());  
        ps.setString(2,usu_bean.getA_paterno());  
        ps.setString(3,usu_bean.getA_materno());  
        ps.setString(4,usu_bean.getDireccion());
        ps.setInt(5, usu_bean.getTelefono());

        status=ps.executeUpdate();  

        con.close();  
    }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}  

    return status;  
}
```

El problema que tengo es cuando quiero insertar en la tabla tipo_usuario porque tiene como FK el id_usuario de la tabla usuario.

Como le hago para que cuando termine de insertar en usuario obtenga el id_usuario del ultimo registro para posteriormente hacer otro insert pero a la tabla tipo_usuario y pasarle el id_usuario del ultimo registro de la tabla usuario que piden la tabla tipo_usuario como FK.

> Tabla tipo_usuario
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> Metodo que intengo crear para insertar en tipo_usuario

```
public static int saveTipo(UsuarioBean usu_bean){
    Connection con = null;
    int status=0;  

    try{  
        con = Conexion.getConnection(); 
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(  
                     "insert into tipo_usuario (tipo, num_empleado, password, usuario_id_usuario) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");  
        ps.setInt(1,usu_bean.getTipo());  
        ps.setInt(2,usu_bean.getNum_empleado());  
        ps.setString(3,usu_bean.getPassword());  
        ps.setInt(4,);

        status=ps.executeUpdate();  

        con.close();  
    }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}  

    return status;  
}
```

Pero falta colocar el usuario_id_usuario que esta como FK.

Espero que me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 2):

La forma sugerida de lograr esto es agregando el parámetro `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` a la llamada a `con.prepareStatement()` cuando insertas el usuario:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
                     "insert into usuario (nombres, a_paterno, a_materno, direccion, telefono) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                     Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Al hacer esto, después de ejecutar `ps.executeUpdate();` puedes averiguar el `id` del registro que se acaba de insertar usando el código siguiente:

```
status = ps.executeUpdate();

try (ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
    if (!rs.next()) throw new RuntimeException("no devolvió el ID");

    int idUsuario = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

Luego, cómo transmites este ID al código que lo necesita para insertar en la tabla `tipo_usuario`, eso tu lo puedes determinar. Me imagino que una forma de hacerlo sería poniendo al día tu instancia de `UsuarioBean` con el ID obtenido, algo como:

```
usu_bean.setIdUsuario(rs.getInt(1));
```

... lo que entonces te permitiría usar ese valor cuando seteas los parámetros para insertar en la tabla `tipo_usuario`:

```
ps.setInt(4, usu_bean.getIdUsuario());
```

---

Viendo que hicistes esta otra pregunta, [Como obtengo mi dato de un SELECT MAX(id_usuario) FROM usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124562/como-obtengo-mi-dato-de-un-select-maxid-usuario-from-usuario) después de formular esta pregunta, asumo que estabas tratando solucionar este problema por medio de buscar el ID máximo en tu tabla `usuario` para encontrar el último ID insertado.

Te recomiendo fuertemente de evitar usar esa solución. Por un lado, estás agregando el costo adicional innecesario de tener que recorrer la tabla para conseguir un ID. Pera aún más importante, cabe la posibilidad de que corrompas tus datos si 2 hilos insertan un usuario en paralelo, porque terminarías ligando 2 registros en `tipo_usuario` al mismo usuario por error.

Para evitar estos problemas, es mejor usar el método descrito arriba.