# Como obtengo mi dato de un SELECT MAX(id_usuario) FROM usuario

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo mi siguiente método donde quiero obtener el ultimo registro de mi tabla usuario, pero me está trayendo 0 cuando me debería de traer 4.
¿Dónde está fallando?

> Metodo

```
public static int getIdOfEmployee(){
    Connection con = null;
    int id_usuario = 0;

    try{  
        con = Conexion.getConnection();  
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT MAX(id_usuario) FROM usuario");   
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        id_usuario = rs.getInt(1); 

        con.close();  
    }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}  

    return id_usuario;  
}
```

> Tabla usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Consulta donde si me arroja el resultado correcto en MYSQL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: Al ejecutar "SELECT MAX(id_usuario) FROM usuario" desde mysql si le arroja el 4?

Comment: Seguramente estás recibiendo un error. Seguro no ves los detalles del error debido a tu sentencia `ex.printStackTrace();`?

Comment: Hola si, ahí si lo arroja

Comment: si ejecuto el query en mysql si sale 4

Comment: Si recibes un error, no crees que es importante compartirlo en tu pregunta?

Comment: no me esta marcando error poque si esta retornando el dato pero me esta arrojado 0

Comment: pero esta arrojando el 4 que debe de ser

Comment: Por favor, verifica principalmente que le estes pegando a la misma base en las dos instancias donde corres el query. probaste hacer un count de registros, o ejecutar un select y ver cual es el primer registro?

Comment: pondre una captura de el query pero en mysql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que debes ejecutar `rs.next()` antes de poder leer el resultado.

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
rs.next(); // te falta esto
id_usuario = rs.getInt(1);
```

Debido a esto, la llamada a `rs.getInt(1);` debe estar lanzándote una excepción.

Pero como has escogido *ignorar* el error en tu `try-catch`, entonces recibes el valor con que inicializastes la variable `id_usuario` al principio del método, o sea `0`.

Aparte de que debes incluir la llamada a `rs.next()`, esto debería servir de lección de que no es buena idea atrapar e ignorar una excepción si no la vas a manejar, porque simplemente resultará en otro error en tu programa, pero que parecerá aun más misterioso.

Entiendo que con Java esto se puede volver fastidioso, porque si no manejas la excepción, entonces te obliga a marcar el método con `throws SQLException`, y esto a su vez tiene un efecto en cascada con los métodos más arriba en la pila de llamadas. Pero si quieres evitar este problema, en vez de callar la excepción, mejor es la relazes como un `RuntimeException`:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Adicionalmente, toma la costumbre de cerrar los recursos (conexión, prepared statement, result set, etc...) usando el patrón [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) para evitar problemas.

Código sugerido:

```
public static int getIdOfEmployee() throws SQLException {
    try (Connection con = Conexion.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT MAX(id_usuario) FROM usuario");
         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

        if (!rs.next()) throw new RuntimeException("no hubo resultado");

        return rs.getInt(1);
    }
}
```

... o si realmente quieres evitar el `throws SQLException` en la firma del método:

```
public static int getIdOfEmployee() {
    try (Connection con = Conexion.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT MAX(id_usuario) FROM usuario");
         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

        if (!rs.next()) throw new RuntimeException("no hubo resultado");

        return rs.getInt(1);
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era ese el problema.